# How to write a recursive function in my PHP source code

Tags: php

I want to display the employees in Hierarchical tree structure. I have tried with a loop. But it was so hard to get the output. I'm new to PHP, help me with this, that is, how to write the recursive function in my source code.

```
 <?php
 include_once('config.php');
 $Empname="Prakash";
 $Designation="HR";
 ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div align="right">
<a href="logout.php?Empid=<?php echo $Empid;?>">Logout</a>
</div>
<div id="div">
<h4>EmpName:<?php echo $Empname ;?></h4>
<h4>Designation:<?php echo $Designation ;?></h4>
</div>
<form>
<?php
$selectAF=array();
$i=0;
while($getbyHR=mysql_fetch_array($selectbyHR))
{
$selectAF[$i]=$getbyHR['Empname'];
?>
<table>
<thead>
<th>Empname</th>
<th>Designation</th>
<th>Controlof</th>
<th>Projectstatus</th>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $getbyHR['Empname']?></td>
<td><?php echo $getbyHR['Designation']?></td>
<td><?php echo $getbyHR['Controlof'];?></td>
<td><?php echo $getbyHR['Projectstatus']?></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<table>
<h2>Project managers</h2>
<thead>
<th>Empname</th>
<th>Designation</th>
<th>Controlof</th>
<th>Projectstatus</th>
</thead>
<?php
$selectedPM=array();
$x=0;
for($p=0;$p<count($selectAF);$p++)
{
$PMname=$selectAF[$p];
$selectpm=mysql_query("select * from reports where Controlof='$PMname'");
while($getPM=mysql_fetch_array($selectpm))
{
$selectedPM[$x] =$getPM['Empname'];
?>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $getPM['Empname']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $getPM['Designation'];?></td>
<td><?php echo $getPM['Controlof'];?></td>
<td><?php echo $getPM['Projectstatus'];?></td>
</tr>
<?php
$x++;
}
}
?>
</tbody>
</table>
<table>
<h2>TeamLeaders</h2>
<thead>
<th>Empname</th>
<th>Designation</th>
<th>Controlof</th>
<th>Projectstatus</th>
</thead>
<?php

$selectedTL=array();
$q=0;
for($t=0;$t<count($selectedPM);$t++)
{
$TLname=$selectedPM[$t];
$selectedteamleader=mysql_query("select * from reports where Controlof='$TLname'");
while($getTL=mysql_fetch_array($selectedteamleader))
{
$selectedTL[$q] =$getTL['Empname'];
?>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $getTL['Empname']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $getTL['Designation'];?></td>
<td><?php echo $getTL['Controlof'];?></td>
<td><?php echo $getTL['Projectstatus'];?></td>
</tr>
<?php
$q++;
}
}
?>
</tbody>
</table>
<table>
<thead>
<th>Empname</th>
<th>Designation</th>
<th>Controlof</th>
<th>Projectstatus</th>
</thead>
<h2>SeniorEngineer</h2>
<?php
$selectedSE=array();
$w=0;
for($s=0;$s<count($selectedTL);$s++)
{
$SEname=$selectedTL[$s];
$selectedseniorengineer=mysql_query("select * from reports where Controlof='$SEname'");
while($getSE=mysql_fetch_array($selectedseniorengineer))
{
$selectedSE[$w] =$getSE['Empname'];
?>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $getSE['Empname']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $getSE['Designation'];?></td>
<td><?php echo $getSE['Controlof'];?></td>
<td><?php echo $getSE['Projectstatus'];?></td>
</tr>
<?php
$w++;
}
}
?>
</tbody>
</table>
<table>
<h2>AssistantEngineer</h2>
<thead>
<th>Empname</th>
<th>Designation</th>
<th>Controlof</th>
<th>Projectstatus</th>
</thead>
<?php
$selectedAE=array();
$b=0;
for($a=0;$a<count($selectedSE);$a++)
{
$AEname=$selectedSE[$a];
$selectedassistantengineer=mysql_query("select * from reports where Controlof='$AEname'");
while($getAE=mysql_fetch_array($selectedassistantengineer))
{
$selectedAE[$b] =$getAE['Empname'];
?>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $getAE['Empname']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $getAE['Designation'];?></td>
<td><?php echo $getAE['Controlof'];?></td>
<td><?php echo $getAE['Projectstatus'];?></td>
</tr>
<?php
$b++;
}
}
?>
</tbody>
</table>
<table>
<h2>Execuetive Engineer</h2>
<thead>
<th>Empname</th>
<th>Designation</th>
<th>Controlof</th>
<th>Projectstatus</th>
</thead>
<?php
$selectedEE=array();
$y=0;
for($e=0;$e<count($selectedAE);$e++)
{
$Engineername=$selectedAE[$e];
$selectedengineer=mysql_query("select * from reports where Controlof='$Engineername'");
while($getEE=mysql_fetch_array($selectedengineer))
{
$selectedEE[$y] =$getEE['Empname'];
?>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $getEE['Empname']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $getEE['Designation'];?></td>
<td><?php echo $getEE['Controlof'];?></td>
<td><?php echo $getEE['Projectstatus'];?></td>
</tr>
<?php
$y++;
}
}
?>
</tbody>
</table>
<table>
<h2>Trainee</h2>
<thead>
<th>Empname</th>
<th>Designation</th>
<th>Controlof</th>
<th>Projectstatus</th>
</thead>
<?php
$selectedtrainee=array();
$g=0;
for($r=0;$r<count($selectedEE);$r++)
{
$EEname=$selectedEE[$r];
$selectedTrainee=mysql_query("select * from reports where Controlof='$EEname'");
while($gettrainee=mysql_fetch_array($selectedTrainee))
{
$selectedtrainee[$g] =$gettrainee['Empname'];
?>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $gettrainee['Empname']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $gettrainee['Designation'];?></td>
<td><?php echo $gettrainee['Controlof'];?></td>
<td><?php echo $gettrainee['Projectstatus'];?></td>
</tr>
<?php
$g++;
}
}
?>
</tbody>
</table>
<table>
<h2>Ap</h2>
<thead>
<th>Empname</th>
<th>Designation</th>
<th>Controlof</th>
<th>Projectstatus</th>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php
$selectedAp=array();

for($v=0;$v<count($selectedtrainee);$v++)
{
$Trainee=$selectedtrainee[$v];
$selectedAp=mysql_query("select * from reports where Controlof='$Trainee'");
while($getAp=mysql_fetch_array($selectedAp))
{
?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $getAp['Empname']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $getAp['Designation'];?></td>
<td><?php echo $getAp['Controlof'];?></td>
<td><?php echo $getAp['Projectstatus'];?></td>
</tr>
<?php
}
}
?>
<?php
// while loop of AF
$i++;
}
?>
</tbody>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>


        Table
  Sno|Empname|Designation|Controlof|
   1 |Prakash|HR         |Ram      |
   2 |Sasi   |AF         |prakash  |
   3 |venki  |AF         |prakash  |
   4 |Tom    |PM         |Sasi     |
   5 |orton  |PM         |venki    |
   6 |Ram    |TL         |Tom      |
   7 |David  |SE         |orton    |
If prakash logged into his profile the dashboard has to look like this
    sno |Empname|Designation|controlof
     1   Sasi      AF        prakash
     2   venki     AF        Prakash

Project Managers
   sno |Empname|Designation|Control of    sno |Empname|Designation|Controlof
    1    Tom      PM          Sasi         1    orton   PM           Venki
```

Comment: First things first. What does your schema look like?  First get that planned right and the rest will follow.  Edit your post to show schema and we'll see where we can go from there.

Comment: Can you please provide us with the output from `show create table <your_table_name>;` ?

Comment: Ok, the schema helps quite a bit. I'll type up an answer when I get to a computer. Your schema has the right idea but needs a little tweaking

Comment: Soooo, did that help or did it miss completely?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest start point to reduce your code is to remove common code to a function...

```
function displayEmployees ( $employee ) {
    echo '<tbody>';
    $selected=array();
    $select=mysql_query("select * from reports where Controlof='$employee'");
    while($get=mysql_fetch_array($select))
    {
        $selected[] =$get['Empname'];
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>'.$get['Empname'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$get['Designation'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$get['Controlof']'.</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$get['Projectstatus'].'</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
    }
    echo '</tbody>';
    return $selected;
}
```

Then you can call it at each point you need to display data, so for example...

```
<?php
$selectedPM=displayEmployees($selectAF);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only need one level of hierarchy, recursion is not necessary.  But if you want to show subordinates of subordinates, then recursion is one of the ways to do it.

First, we need to make a change to the schema to make it more reliable.  You *can* match against names, but all it takes is one letter mistyped to break everything.  Use the id to match against. I have renamed `Sno` and `Controlof` to the more typical `id` and `pid` (parent id).  `pid` is simply the id of the employee's manager.  Use `0` or `null` if an employee has nobody over them.

```
      table: Employees
id |pid | employeeName | designation
 1 | 6  | Prakash      | HR
 2 | 1  | Sasi         | AF
 3 | 1  | Venki        | AF
 4 | 2  | Tom          | PM
 5 | 3  | Orton        | PM
 6 | 4  | Ram          | TL
 7 | 5  | David        | SE
```

If you only need to go one level deep, then recursion is not needed; you just need a good sql query, assuming you know the id of the employee that is logged in:

```
SELECT * FROM Employees WHERE pid=?
```

and then bind the logged in employee's id to the placeholder.

> Note: learn how to make queries using prepared statements.  `mysql_query("select * from reports where Controlof='$PMname'");` is vulnerable to SQL injection.

If for some reason you don't know the employee id, you could get there even by searching for the employee's name:

```
SELECT a.* from Employees as a, Employees as b WHERE a.pid=b.id AND a.employeeName LIKE ?
```

Recursion is a little more complicated... and is best done in an object so that you don't have to worry about variable scope.  If you need to go deeper into the hierarchy, let me know and I'll write another answwer.  It's more complicated and deserves a separate answer.